# Huntco Ketchup Solution

Tags: excel, solver

I was trying to solve a transportation problem from Winston problem.The problem is as below:

> Huntco produces tomato sauce at five different plants. The capacity
>   (in tons) of each plant is given in Table 40. The tomato sauce is
>   stored at one of three warehouses. The perton cost (in hundreds of
>   dollars) of producing tomato sauce at each plant and shipping it to
>   each warehouse is given in Table 41. Huntco has four customers. The
>   cost of shipping a ton of sauce from each warehouse to each customer
>   is as given in Table 42. Each customer must be delivered the amount
>   (in tons) of sauce given in Table 43.

```
TAB L E 41
                To
From       Warehouse 1 Warehouse 2 Warehouse 3
Plant 1           8        10               12
Plant 2           7        5                 7
Plant 3           8        6                 5
Plant 4           5        6                 7
Plant 5           7        6                 5

TAB L E 42
           To
From         Customer 1 Customer 2 Customer 3 Customer 4
Warehouse 1         40   80         90           50
Warehouse 2         70   70         60           80
Warehouse 3         80   30         50           60

TAB L E 43

Customer 1   2   3   4
Demand  200 300 150 250
```

My Solution with solver

```
Objective function:Min total annual cost
Decision variable:
Changing cells in solver:  There are four sets of changing cells – two sets for amounts to ship and two sets of binary variables for which plants and warehouses 
as use variable 
Constrains:
Plant upper bounds:  The constraint ShippedOut1<=UpBounds1 gives the 1st inequality.
Warehouse upper bounds:  The constraint ShippedOut2_Col<=UpBounds2 operationalizes the 2nd inequality.
Warehouse balance:  The constraint ShippedIn1=ShippedOut2_ (shipped 1 =shipped 2)
Demand constraints: The constraint ShippedIn2>=Demands ensures that each customer received the required amount.
```

Both use plants and use ships are binary variable

When I formulate and run in solver it keeps giving multiple solution and it gets stuck. How to do it in solver?

Comment: You reference Table 40 but I don't see it in you question.  Not sure if it will be important to others or no.

Comment: Hi,are you able to view now?

Comment: Hi..it was a format problem but are you able to see the tables now ?

Comment: we can see table 41, 42 and 43. you will need to edit your question to help others

Comment: Sorry is the problem not defined correctly?

Comment: Where is table 40?